# GeneXus - Generar QRCode e impirmirlo en un PDF

Tags: genexus, qrcode

buen día con todos.

Se precisa generar un QRCode con 3 datos (nombre, fecha y número) luego de generarlo se necesita que se imprima en un reporte PDF.
Se usa generador Java.

Alguien dispone de un ejemplo de cómo implementarlo ?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ejemplo no tengo, pero podrias consumir una api web que te genere el QR, y luego en la response que trae el qr generado, gardarla en una image e imprimirla en un reporte. Eso probaste y no pudiste?

Answer (score 1):

En el layout del procedure, agregar una variable &QR de tipo Image a un printblock.

Luego en el Source del Procedure que imprime el PDF:

```
&Datos = &Nombre.Trim() + &Fecha.Trim() + &Numero.Trim()
&QR.FromURL('http://sdx.genexus.com/agetqrcode.aspx?' + &Datos.Trim())
Print PrintBlockQueTieneLaVariableQR
```

&Datos char(100)

Comment: Muchas gracias Guido por responder, voy a probarla.


Esta es otra opción que me funcionó:

&Parametros = &PersonaNombre.Trim() + '%0A' + PersonaFechaIngreso.ToString() +  '%0A' + PersonaCupo.ToString()
 &CodigoQR  = 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=200x200&cht=qr&chl=' + &Parametros.Trim()

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Tenía el mismo problema y no estaba pudiendo hacerlo andar con `'http://sdx.genexus.com/agetqrcode.aspx?'` ya que la url que quería poner era muy larga.
La solución que encontré fue la siguiente:

```
&linkqr = 'http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data='+ &URLQR.Trim()

&QRCode.FromURL(&linkqr.Trim())
```

Donde *&linkqr* es una variable de tipo `char` al igual que *&URLQR* y *&QRCode* es de tipo `Image`.